# Leading dot in json key

Tags: json, dropbox-api

Most (if not all) of the json strings returned by the Dropbox API include the `.tag` key.

I wonder why not simply use `tag`, does the leading dot have a meaning in json syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some discussion about this in [this forum thread](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/API-v2-feedback-files-quot-tag-quot-attribute-extremely/m-p/158904):

> It was meant to be in a namespace that would never cause collisions